# C# MySQL table entry counting from user selection

Tags: c#, mysql

I tried to write a code which will count rows in MySQL , same as combobox-selected text.
For example in my MySQL database,i have a table(ogrencikayit) and in this table i have several columns.In my combobox there are 2 different selection which allows to select student class.When user select the class in combobox , label has to show count of total student in selected class.Here is my code;

```
DB database = new DB();
        int kayitsayisi = -1;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select count(*) from ogrencikayit Where ogrsinif ="+comboBox3.Text.ToUpper()+"" , database.baglanti);
        database.baglanti.Open();
        kayitsayisi = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        string kayitt = kayitsayisi.ToString();
        label24.Text = kayitt;
```

Shortly; i try to find a code that it will read the name of the class name from combobox than it will search in database that how many student belongs to that class and it will show it to the label.

Comment: so what's the question here?

Comment: The question is that code is not working.It says Invalid column "class name" in where clause.

Comment: Create queries through [paramerization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx), not through concatenation. You will avoid formatting problems like this for starters. You're otherwise opening yourself to a [world of pain](https://xkcd.com/327/) including SQL injection.

Comment: You have the type wrong methinks... this will solve your issue and make it more secure https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It says Invalid column "class name" in where clause.

that's cause you are missing single quote around the value and thus it's taking it as a column name. it should be like below

```
Where ogrsinif ='"+comboBox3.Text.ToUpper()+"'"
```

Again, always use parameterized query instead of concatenating your user input.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select count(*) from ogrencikayit Where ogrsinif = @ogrsinif" , database.baglanti);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ogrsinif", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=comboBox3.Text;
```

Comment: Thank you guys.Now it's working.

Comment: @A.OZTEPE Fixed it. Try it now. And unless you've done something weird to the MySql defaults, it will do a case-insensitive compare and there's no need to call `.ToUpper()`.

Comment: Yes @JoelCoehoorn  I delete .ToUpper. Thank you for your answer.